# How to link IBM Id with IBM intranet Id so that I can connect to DST database from BlueMix

Tags: ibm-cloud

How can I access IBM BlueMix with intranet Id for internal application.

I've IBM Id and IBM Intranet Id, but I am not able to find the option to merge IBM Id with Intranet Id so that I can access intanet DB.

Comment: Linking the IDs won't make it possible to connect public Bluemix to intranet, just means there is a common password. What you want to do isn't possible.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. If you want to access an IBM internal  Bluemix deployment, you need to open a Bluemix support ticket at https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport.

Comment: I want to access Internal BlueMix for internal application, so as to access DST database.